# Android admob not visible in device using in corona sdk?

Tags: admob, coronasdk

In my application i used ad-mob .i used publisher id.if i set iPhone id it works perfectly but when i use android id it does not show anything. what i did wrong.how to solve this problem.i stuck with 3 days.anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you add the INTERNET permission on android on the build.settings?

Comment: yes.i added on the build.setting.when i used iphone id it shows.

Comment: What device did you use? Both iOS and Android?

Comment: samsung galaxy s duos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build.settings check whether you've added the followings:

```
android =
    {
        usesPermissions =
            {
                "android.permission.INTERNET",
                "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
                "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE",
            },
    }
```

Keep coding.................. :)